# Why python allows tuple as key for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, immutability

tuples in python can have elements of different type. For example:

```
tup1 = ('physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000);
tup2 = (1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

When used for keys in dictionary, how does python decide the size of key when the element size are varied?

Comment: What do you mean the "size of key"?  Python doesn't need to know anything about the "size" of a dictionary key.

Comment: Dictionaries use hashing algorithms to find out the actual key

Comment: Why do you think that the size of the key matters?

Comment: according to python source code, it calculate a hash function called tuplehash(PyTupleObject *v) to calculate the hash value based on the elements of the tuple. I did not see a __eq__ function but I guess that's how python compares two tuples

Comment: The element size does not vary.  If a tuple contains mutable objects (e.g. a tuple of lists) these are references to those objects, not the objects themselves.  The size of the element is the size of a reference, which doesn't change.

Answer (score 6):

Python dictionaries need not know the size of the key. Python dictionaries accept any *object* as a key if it provides the `__hash__` and `__eq__` special methods. Python finds the matching key by `key == another`, which internally calls `key.__eq__(another)`. This also means, that you can have one dictionary that has strings, integers, tuples of 1 and 100 elements as keys at the same time.

To speed things up, a dictionary organizes these keys into a hash table, that uses a hash code calculated with `hash(key)` to divide keys; internally `hash(key)` calls  `key.__hash__()`; a hash code is a simple integer that satisfies two rules:

1. it must be that `hash(key) == hash(another)` if `key == another`
2. the hash key should be chosen so that if `key != another` then preferably (but not in every case) `hash(key) != hash(another)`

In addition in Python `hash(x)` must be constant to the lifetime of `x`, which means that the equality of `x` with regards to other objects must not change either.

A tuple has both `__eq__` and `__hash__`:

```
>>> t = ('physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000)
>>> hash(t)
1710411284653490310
>>> u = ('physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000) # another tuple
>>> t is u  # they are not the same object
False
>>> hash(t) == hash(u)
True
>>> t == u
True
```

Now, Python need not even use the hash code at all to find an object in a dictionary, all it would need is to find an element with matching key, comparing each and every to the given key with `==`. But this would mean that on a dictionary having `n` keys, on average `n / 2` comparisons would have to be made to find a key. With the hashing trick we can narrow the set of keys to compare to ideally always 1 or handful at maximum, thus a lookup in dictionary should be equally fast were it small or large.

---

Now, unlike a tuple, a `list` in Python is a mutable value, and for it it is impossible to provide a unchanging hash code that would also in future satisfy the 2 rules given above. Thus Python does not define it at all:

```
>>> [].__hash__ is None
True
```

likewise you get an exception if using it as a dictionary key:

```
>>> {[]: 42}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 5):

> how does python decide the size of key when the element size are varied?

The simple answer is that it doesn't: Python allows dictionaries with heterogenous keys. This is much broader than different-sized tuples:

```
In [15]: d = {}

In [16]: d[42] = 'foo'

In [17]: d['bar'] = -1

In [18]: d[(1, 2, 3)] = {}

In [19]: d
Out[19]: {42: 'foo', 'bar': -1, (1, 2, 3): {}}
```

Any [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) object, irrespective of its type, can be used as a key into any dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the key does not matter for a dictionary.

Dictionary keys must be immutable. 
Since a tuple is immutable, you can use a tuple as a key to a dict.

[Source](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html)